# Comments section in Contact Form 7 (wordpress) is not working on mobile

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

When I test this page: https://affordablehousepaintingrenosparks.com/get-an-estimate/ on a mobile device (iPad Portrait or lower) my contact form does not allow me to enter any data into the final section (Tell us a little about your project...). I have checked the CSS to see if anything is overlapping and have looked at the code but can't find anything wrong with it.

Here is a screencast of the problem: https://www.loom.com/share/cacb1b51d7674d95ab08246ec1a81760

I would like to be able to enter text into this field. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `clear: both` to the last `<p class="col-md-12">` which wraps the submit button. Then it works! :)